# LWJGL Newbie – What are stackPush (), mallocInt (1) and similar GLFW methods?

Tags: java, malloc, lwjgl, glfw

I'm learning LWJGL for the first time and exploring a simple code block given as an example on the [LWJGL3 site](https://www.lwjgl.org/guide). I have never used OpenGL or GLFW before neither.

I don't understand this small chunk of code. If I remove it, the main code still works. Is this whole thing only to center the window upon creation?

What is `mallocInt (1)` supposed to mean? This whole idea of `stackPush()` and strange method calls has be confused. I have used SWT and awt and never seen anything like it.

```
// Get the thread stack and push a new frame

try ( MemoryStack stack = stackPush() ) {

    IntBuffer pWidth = stack.mallocInt(1); // int*
    IntBuffer pHeight = stack.mallocInt(1); // int*

    // Get the window size passed to glfwCreateWindow
    glfwGetWindowSize(window, pWidth, pHeight);

    // Get the resolution of the primary monitor
    GLFWVidMode vidmode = glfwGetVideoMode(glfwGetPrimaryMonitor());

    // Center the window
    glfwSetWindowPos(window,
        (vidmode.width() - pWidth.get(0)) / 2,
        (vidmode.height() - pHeight.get(0)) / 2);

}

// the stack frame is popped automatically
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

LWJGL allows memory allocations on the stack at speed much faster than pure Java allows through the `MemoryStack` class.  In order to get the stack, you call `stackPush()`.  By putting it in the `try` clause as you have done, it makes it so the stack allocation is thread local and the stack is popped and buffers are freed once the `try` statement is done.

`MemoryStack.mallocXX(count)` (where xx is the type and count is the size of the buffer) is how one goes about allocating from the stack.  `stack.mallocInt(1)` returns an integer buffer of size one from the stack, instead of from the heap.

In general, when you are doing uniforms or anything where you need a buffer, use `MemoryStack.stackPush()`.  LWJGL has a very good article ([here](https://blog.lwjgl.org/memory-management-in-lwjgl-3/)) about the different methods of memory management in LWJGL3, and I definitely recommend taking the time to sit down and learn these new memory techniques.